# JNLP fonts not working

Tags: java, fonts, jnlp, java-web-start

In my program, I use a ttf file for fonts, and when running the jar, the fonts work perfectly, but when run through java web start, the fonts are only half working. my application is a search engine, so when I search, the program is using the font fine, but when I click on a search result to bring up another 2 jframes, a controller and a slide, almost like a powerpoint, the controller has the font right, but the slide doesn't. I feel like it might be because the font is being used by the controller and therefore can't be used by the slide as well, but what can I do to remedy the situation, short of duplicating the font file, and using that for the slide jframe?

Comment: It might depend on how you install your fonts: by [GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423007/java-swing-jlabel-html-and-custom-fonts) should do. Maybe there is a problem getting the font resource; use an absolute path "/.../... .ttf".

Comment: well i don't think it's a problem with getting it as a resource because it works in every jframe except one. and it's only a problem when I use the jnlp file, if I use the jar, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: *"another 2 jframes"*  If you mean `JFrame` then 2 points.  1) Use correct capitals so it is clear. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Ah yes, I do mean JFrame. Also, the way my program is meant to be used, I'm not sure if there is any other way to do it. With a controller that changes the content of a slide, that's meant to be projected onto another screen. Not sure how else to do it if not with 2 JFrames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user needed the font installed as well. Kind of an obvious answer...